# Sending emails to multiple recipients without disclosing them to each other

Tags: email, outlook, gmail, sendmail

I want to send an email in to multiple people via the `To:` field without them knowing that the email was sent to other people.

For the recipient it should look like this:

```
TO: xyz@mail.com
```

But the actual list should be:

```
TO: xyz@mail.com; pqr@gmail.com; someone@company.com; everyone@sayari.com;
```

So is it possible to send an email like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are aware of BCC and don't want to use that...

You would need to use an ESP (email service provider) to do this. As Dmitry mentioned, you'd have to send a separate email to each recipient. An ESP can automate that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a separate message for each recipient.

Comment: Pleases show your current code that sends to multiple recipients.